# InputStream does not detect null and goes on forever Client-Server communication

Tags: java, server, client, inputstream, executorservice

I have a Multi-Threaded Client-Server application.
If the server is told to shutdown, the Executor(ExecutorServices) does not accept any new incoming requests, therefore he gets no reply(NULL).

This is my code do deal with it:

```
while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null && !clientClose) {
                if(in==null) break;
                out.println(userInput);
                System.out.println("echo: " + in.readLine());
```

And this the console output I receive from my client(I typed r and then lots of dots):

```
Client started
r
echo: null
.
echo: null
.
echo: null
.
echo: null
```

So he even receives a `null` - Why does he not stop then?

This is the code on the Server side in case you need it:

```
public class MulServer_v1 {

    protected static int portNumber = 8540;
    protected static int max_Clients = 3;
    protected static boolean shutdownFlag = false;
    protected static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    protected static ExecutorService executor;
    protected static ArrayList<Socket> socketList = new ArrayList<>();

    public MulServer_v1(int portNumber, int poolSize) {
    }

    public void runServer() {

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
            executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(max_Clients);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not create server on specific port");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        while (!shutdownFlag) {
            try {
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                socketList.add(clientSocket);
                executor.submit(new RequestHandler_v1(clientSocket));

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Couldn't accept on the Socket");
                executor.shutdown();
                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (RejectedExecutionException re){
                re.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("The server is shutting down, new connections cannot be made");                  
            }

        }
        shutdownAndAwaitTermination();
    }   


    protected static void shutdownAndAwaitTermination() {
        shutdownFlag = true;
        System.out.println("Shutting down..");
        executor.shutdown(); // Disable new tasks from being submitted

        try {
            // Wait a while for existing tasks to terminate
            if (!executor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                for (Socket s : socketList) {

                    try {
                        s.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println("Couldn't close the socket");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                executor.shutdownNow();
                // Cancel currently executing tasks
                System.out.println("komme ich hierhin?");

                // Wait a while for tasks to respond to being cancelled
                if (!executor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                    System.err.println("Pool did not terminate");
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            // (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted
            executor.shutdownNow();
            // Preserve interrupt status
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        try {
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Serversocket konnte nicht geschlossen werden");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("I got here!");
        // for (Socket s : socketList) {
        // if (s != null) {
        // try {
        // s.close();
        // } catch (IOException e) {
        // System.out.println("Couldn't close the socket");
        // e.printStackTrace();
        // }
        // }
        // }
    }
```

Comment: You don't actually test `in.readLine()` so why would it stop?

Comment: I suggest you close the serverSocket first, then shutdown the executor before closing the connections. Otherwise you have a race condition where new connections could be added after you have closed them all (all the ones you started with)  Note: ArrayList is not thread safe so you might not see the last Sockets added.

Comment: @PeterLawrey peter i just saw it too, in!= null is invalid instead in.readLine()!=null should be used

Comment: @PavneetSingh I think the OP is reading from System.in so that needs to be tested too.

Comment: @PeterLawrey there is basically not much clue for me , OP just want want to stop when it's null so we tried to guide as much as we could ,rest i am sure we will be notified if something else go wrong :P:P

Comment: Thanks for your replies. 3 Things
1) How do I test then I do net get a reply? I can't justp ut in.readLine()!=null into the while loop, then the whole System is stuck and nothing happens at all
2)I cannot close the Sockets before the executor shutdown, because I want the currently clients still give a certain amount of time to interact with the server
3)Well what else as ArrayList could I use?
I know my coding is horrible I am trying to improve here so thank you a lot for responding guys!

Comment: In case you want to see the whole code:
http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/142970/multi-threaded-server-client-communication-where-clients-can-signal-the-server-t